# How do I merge and delete existing primary key on new database?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with same structures.

`current_db` = 521,892 rows and primary key is `email`

`new_db` = 575,992 rows and primary key is `email`

On `new_db` I want delete existing `email` address which already in `current_db`.

Question :

How do I compare & delete existing `email` on `new_db` and the results on `new_db` only be `54,100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the rows you want to delete -

```
SELECT n.* FROM new_db n
  JOIN current_db c
    ON n.email = c.email;
```

Delete them -

```
DELETE n
FROM new_db n
  JOIN current_db c
    ON n.email = c.email;
```

Answer (score 1):

if indexes matches you can do it in one shot with something like:

```
delete from new_table where id in (select id from old_table)
```

Otherwise you have to modify the query according to your matching fields

```
delete from new_table where id in (select id from old_table where oldtable.field = newtable.field)
```

Of course you have to pay attention on what you actually delete, my suggestion is to delete in two pass (creating a temporary table and changing the delete into an insert into temp_table) and then check if effectively everythings is correct.

(Under Oracle there's the minus operator which shows the difference between two recordset, hopefully there's something similar in your database enviroment).

minus op works like:

```
select * from table_a
minus 
select * from table_b
```

Starting with 2 identical tables, it gives only rows with different field values.

Is straightforward how to cross check with count(*) if everything is fine with the data.
Don't know if for your RDBMS exists something alike, but I think that a fast search on google may help.

Comment: `x IN (SELECT y FROM z)` is not very well optimized in MySQL. It's better to use `JOIN` or `EXISTS` solutions in this case.

Comment: sorry don't know about this limitation of MySQL. Usually I try to avoid joins when I can achieve fixed execution time queries. But I guess it depends on numbers and application scope. However thanks for the information. Cheers.

Comment: In your second query the `where id in (select * ...` should be `where id in (select id ...` or `where id = (select id ...`

Comment: It's not exactly a limitation (the query will run) but the execution plan will not be the best when the tables are big.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE n
FROM new_db n
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM current_db c
    WHERE c.email = n.email
  )
```